# DNSHostNotFound: Failed to look up service "":This operation returned because the timeout period expired

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to connect my mongo shell 4.4.0 with Atlas in windows 10

```
mongo "mongodb+srv://cluster0.bcfqc.mongodb.net/<dbname>" --username xxx
```

But keep getting an error

```
DNSHostNotFound: Failed to look up service "":This operation returned because the timeout period expired.
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your DNS provider block the address. Try to use Google DNS: 8.8.8.8 in your network setting